# Logstash: Filter out heterogeneous logs on a single UDP input

Tags: input, udp, logstash, elastic-stack

I am taking over an infrastructure where **ELK** (ElasticSearch/Logstash/Kibana) has been designed as a PoC then turned into a production service.

There is currently a single UDP `input`, on which multiple remote hosts (mainly firewalls from various vendors) are sending their logs.

As there is no consistency on log format, **I wonder what is the best practice** (I know both solutions are possible) regarding this issue:

- Create as much `input`s in Logstash than I have of firewall devices, and ask my network administrator to kindly change the port where logs are forwarded to (e.g. port 10001 for Juniper, port 10002 for Cisco, ...).
- Use many patterns in `filter` to identify which device type is talking to Logstash, then apply a `type` tag for the transformation and `output`.

*PS: I know that UDP listener is not the best solution in order to keep all the logs, but I have to do with it right now.*

Thanks a lot